# Why does the second product dynamically added to the cart loose it's options in Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2, cart

I am dynamically adding products to the cart in Magento2 with some custom options. Every product has the same base product id with different options. `Represent Product` has been properly overridden so that all products added to the cart are separate. However with this code, the second product added will lose it's custom options:

```
$magento_product = $this->productRepository->get('simple-product-1');
$params = array(
    'product' => $magento_product->getId(),
    'qty'     => intval(5),
    'options' => array(
        'cr_price' => 12.0,
        'Product' => "Test P",
        'cr_XML' => '<root></root>'
    ),
);
$this->cart->addProduct($magento_product, $params);
$params = array(
    'product' => $magento_product->getId(),
    'qty'     => intval(10),
    'options' => array(
        'cr_price' => 14.0,
        'Product' => "Test P2",
        'cr_XML' => '<root></root>'
    ),
);
$this->cart->addProduct($magento_product, $params);
$this->cart->save();
```

Only the first product has an entry in the `quote_item_option` table.

Any thoughts on why or how to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: magento.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - It's perfectly fine for this site though. It's about programming, it has code, it explains what's going wrong, and what it should do. It appears to be a [mcve]. It's actually a very good question.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks - I've posted there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force reloading the product between each add fixes this issue.

```
$this->productRepository->get('simple-product-1', false, null, true);
```

The last `true` parameter is `forceReload`.